# Share image on twitter in IOS

Tags: ios, twitter

HI I want to share Image on twitter from my APP. I have tweet text succesfully by following code.How can I tweet image with text.

```
-(IBAction)updateTwitter{

    if(!_engine){  
        _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];  
        _engine.consumerKey    = kOAuthConsumerKey;  
        _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;  
    }  
    if(![_engine isAuthorized]){

        UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];  
        if (controller){  
            [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES]; 
        }  
    } 

    if([_engine isAuthorized]){
        [_engine sendUpdate:@"This is my first test"];  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using iOS 5's [Twitter Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html)? In particular, check out [TWTweetComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010943), which lets you add images easily.